# How to print 3 copy of bill from crystal report?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010

I m making bill software .
i want to print 3 copy of bill 
1. Buyer copy
2. Original Copy
3. Duplicate copy
i want above text is written on bill on right upper side!
and this event is occurs on one button click !!!!

like 
on first page- Buyer copy
on second page- Original copy
on third page- Duplicate copy